# Generate MAC address in Go

Tags: go

I'm looking for an example on how to generate a MAC Address in Go.
I have found many examples on creating UUIDs but nothing on MAC addresses.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is how I would do it ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/dSTPF8v2idT))

```
import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "fmt"
)

const (
    local     = 0b10
    multicast = 0b1
)

func main() {
    buf := make([]byte, 6)
    _, err := rand.Read(buf)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
        return
    }
    // clear multicast bit (&^), ensure local bit (|)
    buf[0] = buf[0]&^multicast | local
    fmt.Printf("Random MAC address: %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n", buf[0], buf[1], buf[2], buf[3], buf[4], buf[5])
}
```

Note the setting of the local bit which means it won't clash with any globally administered addresses ([see wikipedia for more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address))

Comment: `buf[0] =  (buf[0] | 2) & 0xfe // Set local bit, ensure unicast address`
In most cases you'll want to set the lowest bit to zero, ensuring that you have unicast address, rather than a multicast address.

Comment: `rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())` add this if you want randomness based on timestamp

Comment: @IvanAracki you're thinking `math/rand`. there's no way to seed `crypto/rand` anyway.